# Interface constraints in Dart

Tags: types, casting, dart

I'm porting one of my libraries from Ruby to Dart to get a feel for the language and so far things are going pretty good. The language feels ok and it doesn't have too many rough edges. Now given that Dart is optionally typed I could just give everything a dynamic type and call it a day but that would be kinda pointless. So I've been adding types wherever possible but there are a few places where I can't quite figure out what to do. The basic problem is pretty simple. I'm working with objects that basically have the following interface

```dart
abstract class Indexable {
  Matchable operator [](int index);
}

abstract class Matchable {
  bool operator ==(dynamic other);
}
```

Now pretty much everything supports `Matchable` but not everything supports `Indexable` even though theoretically many things could do so. Doing the obvious thing doesn't work. I can't just typecast with `as` because my tests show that both `String` and `List` throw exceptions when I try to cast them to `Indexable`. The other solutions I can think of are wrappers and reflection but both feel like hacks and add a whole bunch of unnecessary boilerplate because both `String` and `List` already implement the relevant operator.

Some pseudo code for the use case I'm imagining

```dart
List<Matchable> matches(Indexable sequence, List<Matchable> matchers) {
  int index = 0;
  Matchable element;
  List<Matchable> accumulator = [];

  while ((element = sequence[index++]) != null) {
    if (matchers.any((m) => m == element)) {
      accumulator.add(element);
    }
  }

  return accumulator;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a "common" operation on classes that don't share an interface with that operation in it, your need to either use `dynamic` as type or do dynamic type checking where you use it `if (x is String) something(x[index]); else if (x is List) ...`.

Dart once had a type called `Sequence<T>` with `T operator[](int index)` and `int get length` as interface. That was removed because we didn't feel it carried its own weight. There were only really two implementations, `List` and `String`, and it was more like a accident that String happened to match - using the [] operator on String isn't really recommended since it breaks up surrogate pairs.

In your case, I'd just use List for Indexable, and ignore that String happens to be Indexable too, unless the original program depended on that.